# 'CompanyUser' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django

Doing a Get (TastyPie) I'm getting the following error:

> error_message": "'CompanyUser' object has no attribute 'all'",
>   /resources.py\", line 832, in full_dehydrate\n bundle.data[field_name]
>   = field_object.dehydrate(bundle, for_list=for_list)\n\n File \"/Users/user/Documents/workspace/membergetmember/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\",
>   line 818, in dehydrate\n for m2m in the_m2ms.all():\n\nAttributeError:
>   'CompanyUser' object has no attribute 'all'\n"

From my understanding this should work, what have I done wrong? Code below.

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
        resource_name = 'CompanyUser'

class CampaignCreateResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToManyField(UserResource, 'user', full=False)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Campaign.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'campaign'
        allowed_methods = ['post', 'get']
        authentication = APIAuthentication().get_authentication()
        authorization = UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization()
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=CampaignForm)
        excludes = ['id']
```

**Model**

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text="Give your campaign a name i.e Xmas Offer")
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),  related_name='user', null=True)
```

Comment: what version of Django?

Comment: @mconlin using 1.5.x version and AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CompanyUser'

Comment: I assume it works fine if you use queryset = CompanyUser.objects.all() but you want to use the auth goodness as intended...

Comment: @mconlin No I get the same error if I change it to  CompanyUser.objects.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user',  full=True)
```

**Note:** `ToOneField` and then we add `full=true` to show all the details.